# What are the advantages of using mysql_multi vs. a seperate configuration file?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 seperate MySQL 8 instances running on Ubuntu 20.04. One starts via systemd "normaly" and the other one I can invoke by using:

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/home/username/mysqld_replica.cnf &
```

Now that everything is running I was investigating on how to start the second instance on boot. I discovered mysqld_mulit and wonder now if:

1. What are the advantages of mysqld_multi over seperate config files?
2. How I can start the second instance on boot if not using mysqld_multi

Comment: why multiple instances on a server at all? there are only s much resources that have to be shared.

Comment: I want to seperate a replica instance from a staging instance.

Comment: I thought that _multi was no longer supported and Docker was the preferred way?

Answer (score 1):

Some advantages of using mysqld_multi:

- You can start, stop, or restart all the instances with one command.
- You can use one config file, keeping the config options common to all instances in a `[mysqld]` section, and only the instance-specific options in the instance section.

If you don't use mysqld_multi, you would need to create your own systemd entry for your second instance.